# Autocorrelation function

Tags: convolution, autocorrelation

For what signal applies, that its autocorrelation function at point $0$ is zero, i.e. $R_f(0) = 0\ ?$

I know that autocorrelation is (RootMeanSquare)^2 and for $R_f(0)$ this
equals:
$$
R_f(0) = \frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(t)^2 dt = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \lvert c_k\rvert^2
$$

But I have no idea how to formulate that signal from equation.

Thank you very much for hint that will guide me to the right way of solving this problems.

Comment: So if $R_f(0)$ equals $0$, can you say what that implies for $f(t)$? No? Do you understand the concept of integral as the _area_  the graph of $[f(t)]^2$ and the $t$ axis?

Comment: You really shouldn't ask two different questions in the same question. Imagine someone would like to answer one, but not the other - then they've got no chance to be accepted as answer! So, remove the second question from your question (ask it separately).

Comment: @MarcusMüller done

Comment: @DilipSarwate thank you for your reaction, but I wasn't sure where to fit zeros in the formula, because of 'T' and 't' in the equation.

Comment: $R_f(0) = 0$ is given. $R_f(0) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2$ is what your book says. Put the two together to get $\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty |c_k|^2 = 0$. So, the sum of all the terms for which $|c_k|^2$ is positive is cancelled out by sum of all the terms for which $|c_k|^2$ is negative. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Ok, thank you for your effort to help me althrough not all your advice is entirely clear to me. https://www.scribd.com/document/366101861/CASS-Lectures ->This is practicaly the only study material I have (as a student) for preparation on my exam from exercises like these, as you can see there is always a short definition and a heap of formulas and 2-max 3 exercises which I have solved from lessons in my notebook. However this is not enough for me, I'd need to have read up more solved problems and deduce the procedure of solving other problems from that.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Would you have some more study materials which could help me? I'm writing a semester test on Monday from these exercises but I feel still very confused in this topic. Thank you

Comment: Hint: $|c_k|^2 \geq 0$ in all cases, and so there are no $k$ such that $|c_k|^2 < 0$. So, if $\sum_k |c_k|^2 = 0$, it must _also_ be the case that there are no $k$ such that $|c_k|^2 > 0$: there is nothing to cancel them out! In short, it must be that $|c_k|^2 = 0$ for _all_ $k$ for _any_ signal such that $R_f(0) = 0$. Please _write down_ $$f(t) = \text{Fourier series for } f(t)$$ using the fact that you have just proved that $|c_k|^2 = 0$ for all $k$ and stare very hard at the resulting equation.

Answer (score 0):

This (and your other question) is really a clear task to look up the very basic (and unambiguous) definition of the entity at hand (here: the *autocorrelation*, there *length of a convolution*) and simply apply that definition.

So: since you're asking for a hint:

Simply write down the formula for the autocorrelation of a signal. Calculate what it is at 0, set that to zero and get your signal.

You got the formula for autocorrelation at 0 in your question, but you copied it from somewhere and denied yourself the chance to actually see what's happening.

You also seem to be prone to using formulas without being sure what the symbols in these mean (your $t$ vs $T$ confusion). So, read the page leading up to that formula.

Comment: The question asked, right up front, is "What signal has an autocorrelation value of $0$ at $t=0$ or $\tau=0$, i.e. $R_f(0) = 0$?